# ValidationMessageFor only working for some fields

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

In my form, there are some fields which do not seem to be applying the `data-val="true"` property or any of the other `data-val` properties (i.e. `data-val-required`, `data-val-number`, etc.). The first 2 fields are not working but the latter fields are working.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PO_Form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PoNumber, "PO #", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PoNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PoNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        // doesn't work
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Customer PO #", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vendPoNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vendPoNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        // doesn't work
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.poDate, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), @class = "form-control datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.poDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Company", "companyID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="partialView">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("_CompanyDropdown", Model);  }
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.companyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.salesTax, "salesTax", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.salesTax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.salesTax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        // works
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.shipping, "shipping", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.shipping, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.shipping, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        // works
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="createPO" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PurchaseOrders")"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancel</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Database First SQL with Entity Framework generated...

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string PoNumber { get; set; }
    public string vendPoNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime poDate { get; set; }
    public int companyID { get; set; }
    public decimal salesTax { get; set; }
    public decimal shipping { get; set; }
```

How would I use server side validation?
Several fields are required but `[required]` was never generated for these field from EF update.

Comment: What validation attributes are you expecting? - both `PoNumber` and `vendPoNumber` are `string` and can be `null` - you do not have any validation attributes applied to those properties

Comment: In my SQL, all of those fields in question do not allow nulls.

Comment: Just add the `[Required]` attrbute to those 2 properties

Comment: I updated the model through EF. I am not sure why it didn't add the [required] since it is coming from the SQL database. Also, I didn't want to edit the models in case I add more fields or edit any fields in this table during development.

Comment: Are you using database first or code first? In any case that's a separate issue. Unless a `string` property is decorated with validation attributes, no `data-val-*` attributes will be rendered since its not required.

Comment: What is the process to use server side with EF database first?

Comment: I gave you a link in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129282/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-beengie)